Remove object dynamic id from array of objects
Given the following structure I'm trying to remove and flatten the array of objects to be the same as the objectArrayResult below.
const objectArray = [
   {
      "dynamicID1": {
         'key1': 'value1'
      },
      "dynamicID2": {
          'key2': 'value2'
      },
   }
]

The result should be:
const objectArrayResult = [
    {
        'key1': 'value1'
    },
    {
        'key2': 'value2'
    }
]


What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Please provide your attempt at the problem.

It looks like you're wanting to map over the array and unwrapping each object.

You can use Object.values to get an array of the values of each object, flattening the result with Array#flatMap.


const objectArray = [
   {
      "dynamicID1": {
         'key1': 'value1'
      },
      "dynamicID2": {
          'key2': 'value2'
      },
   }
];
const res = objectArray.flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(res);



